# npm install hangs forever in EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, npm-install

Trying to deploy a react app on AWS EC2.
I'm using apache so I got git clone under /var/www/html.

I didn't have any problem when I deployed other projects,
but when I `npm install` in this new project folder, within some seconds (when it's installing webpack), it just stuck at the same point with the same message.
[image]

It stuck there forever and any other command doesn't work. So I have to force quit the terminal. After that, I can't connect on my EC2 instance for 10 - 20min.

I tried `npm install --verbose`, removing package-lock.json, `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ --global`, `npm cache verify` ... nothing worked.

It's really frustrating.
I don't know what should I do. Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

In my case, i had to create a swap file on my micro ec2 instance. My npm install hanged and was killed eventually. Once i increased the memory with the swap file, all worked fine!

Commands i used:

```
fallocate -l 4G /swapfile
chmod 600 /swapfile
mkswap  /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
swapon  --show
free -h
```

To make the swapfile persistent across reboots (run as root):

```
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: Sir, you are a life saviour. I was hoping no to have to make a new instance just for instaling npm modules. This reply should be marked as the answer!

Comment: thank you sir, saved me ton of resources and headaches

Comment: You're literally saving small businesses. Thankyou.

Comment: This one works fine on t2.micro

Answer (score 5):

What type of EC2 instance are you using? check monitoring data, cpu usage and memory consumption
in my experience, "npm install" hangs easily on an EC2 micro instance, if you have a lot of dependencies.

Comment: If I have a micro, how to prevent the hanging?

Comment: One solution could be using a better instance with higher processor performance and memory just to install dependencies, take a snapshot, then use a micro ec2 instance with this snapshot.

Comment: micro is clearly underdesigned.

Answer (score 2):

avoid using `npm install` if its micro instance try `yarn install` it will do the same job with smaller C.P.U usage

when I used `npm i` my instance hangout and I have to restart it with yarn its working smoothly

[image]